# Why "class" cannot be use as tag name in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey

I have a POJO which contain a field need to be output to XML with tag name "class".

Using Jersey 2.0, if the client request a JSON response, the JSON object output correctly with attribute name "class".

However, if the client request an XML output, Jersey fail with a HTTP 500 internal error.

Checked that the statement causing the error is

`@XmlElement(name = "class")
private int vclass;`

Removing the XmlElement annotation and allow the XML to use vclass as tag name work fine.

How could I instruct JAXB to use **class** as tag name ??

Comment: This is most likely NOT the problem with `@XmlElement(name = "class")`. I had `class` elements on many occasions with no problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

> Why “class” cannot be use as tag name in JAXB

You can use "class" as a tag name in JAXB.

---

### What Issue You are Probably Hitting

By default JAXB treats public properties as mapped.  Since you annotated a field you were most likely getting an exception about a duplicate mapped property.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "vclass"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int forum27241550.Foo.getVclass()
        at forum27241550.Foo
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private int forum27241550.Foo.vclass
        at forum27241550.Foo
```

### Why What You Did Fixed It

You posted the following as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27241725/383861):

> Finally found out what's wrong.
>
> Don't know why the annotation in variable declaration statement will
>   cause problem.
>
> Putting the @XmlElement annotation in the setter method work fine.

When you moved the annotation to the property the field was no longer considered mapped, so there was no duplicate mapping problem.

### How to Keep the Annotation on the Field

To annotate a field you should use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on the class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement(name = "class")
    private int vclass;

    public int getVclass() {
        return vclass;
    }

    public void setVclass(int vclass) {
        this.vclass = vclass;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what's wrong.

Don't know why the annotation in variable declaration statement will cause problem.

Putting the @XmlElement annotation in the setter method work fine.